# XACML and WCF Examples & Documentation

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, saml, xacml

What is the status of XACML/SAML .NET Framwork Classesd/Methods?

Will Microsoft provide an .NET XACML/SAML stack/framework now or in the near future?

Can MSDN provide today working examples that demonstrates how to use or implement an XACML/SAML environemtn, those securing a typical WCF client / WCF Service environment?

Given the Microsoft .NET Framwork does not have today (25. february 2014) a XACML/SAML implementation, what third party vendor products would Microsoft recommend to use joint with .NET Framework Classes in a WCF .NET environemnt?

Yes I've googled around, and no, not much helpful comes up. 
There is a severe lacking of useful info on this subject out there.

Any of the following information you could share would be helpful:
1. Can anyone in this Forum or at MSDN Help Desk explain or lead me to documentation explaining the basic protocol flow used when securing a WCF client servevice with XACML? I hope this question fits MSDN Help DESK ;-)

2a). How do I setup a proper formatted XACML/SAML request at the client? 
2b). How do I intercept and extract a properly formatted XACML/SAML request at the service?
2c). How do I pass itto the XACML/SAML processing framwork of .NET (if any) or
2d). any recommended XACML/SAML third party framework?

1. In general: How do I write an message interceptor and retrieve the SAML part in the header to be treated by the XACML service side implementation to receive a permission true/fals value based on policies?
2. What .NET Framework/Classes/Methods will help me to inject XACML/SAML data into a request/message
3. What .NET Framework/Classes/Methods will help me to retriev XACML/SAML data from a request/message

Comment: I find it a bit dubious that you are freely mixing SAML and XACML here. While they might have overlapping areas where they are useful, they are totally different languages with different purposes. I agree though that there is not a lot of information on how to use either of them in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple locations where you could write a policy enforcement point (PEP) in C# .NET. Possible locations include:

- HttpModule
- WCF Web Service - Custom ServiceAuthorizationManager
- REST API (ASP.NET Web API) - Custom AuthorizationFilter
- ASP.NET MVC - Custom AuthorizationFilter

Axiomatics (disclaimer: I work for Axiomatics) provides all these integration points along with a XACML 3.0 PDP written in .NET and a .NET PEP SDK so that you can write your own PEPs.